# QGIS 3.24 on Ubuntu 22.04 issue with SIP Python support is disabled

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

I'm not able to load any plugin on a freshly installed QGIS 3.24.2 (I step by step followed the documentation available here: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu) on Ubuntu 22.04.

Here's the error message when launching QGIS:

```
Couldn't load SIP module.
Python support will be disabled.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/__init__.py", line 78, in 
    from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/PyQt/QtCore.py", line 24, in 
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so: undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm, version Qt_5

Python version:
3.10.4 (main, Apr  2 2022, 09:04:19) [GCC 11.2.0]

QGIS version:
3.24.2-Tisler 'Tisler', 13c1a02865

Python path:
['/usr/share/qgis/python',    
'/home/username/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python',    
'/home/username/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins',    
'/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins',    
'/usr/lib/python310.zip',    
'/usr/lib/python3.10',    
'/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',    
'/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages',    
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

And indeed, Python support *is* disabled.

Any hint on how to solve this?

Here my apt source file for QGIS:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_qgis_org_ubuntu-jammy.list 
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu jammy main
# deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu jammy main
```

and

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy qgis
qgis:
  Installed: 1:3.24.2+36jammy
  Candidate: 1:3.24.2+36jammy
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.24.2+36jammy 500
        500 https://qgis.org/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.22.4+dfsg-3build1 500
        500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
```

[image: QGIS about window]

Some more info on installed Qt packages (they came when QGIS was installed):

```
$ pip3 list | grep -i qt
PyQt5                         5.15.6
PyQt5-Qt5                     5.15.2
PyQt5-sip                     12.10.1
PyQtWebEngine                 5.15.5
PyQtWebEngine-Qt5             5.15.2
QtAwesome                     1.1.1
qtconsole                     5.3.0
QtPy                          2.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp          1.0.3
```